# Angular and date from PHP InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "[object Object]" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Tags: php, angular, date-pipe

I have application written in Angular 9 and api written in PHP. From controller in PHP I return list of objects with property finishDate. In PHP finishDate is assign to DateTime:

```
$timeSheetsOrderDTO1 = new TimeSheetsOrderDTO;
$timeSheetsOrderDTO1->orderId = 62131;
$timeSheetsOrderDTO1->finishDate = new DateTime();
$timeSheetsOrderDTO1->count = 8;
```

TimeSheetsOrderDTO in TypeScript:

```
export class TimeSheetsOrderDTO {
  public orderId: number;
  public finishDate: Date;
  public count: number;
}
```

In TypeScript (Angular) I see data from controller as below:

```
this.timesheetsOrders: Array(4)
0:
count: 8
finishDate: {date: "2020-12-26 15:49:15.052904", timezone_type: 3, timezone: "UTC"}
orderId: 62131
```

I want to display `finishDate` in html. When I have code like this:

```
{{ timesheetsOrder.finishDate }}
```

I see:
[image: date like Object object]

When I write like that:

```
{{ timesheetsOrder.finishDate | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

I get error:

```
core.js:6241 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "[object Object]" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your attempt, `timesheetsOrder.finishDate` refers to the entire object and not the date property within it which is why you get an error.

Use the following syntax:

```
{{ timesheetsOrder.finishDate.date | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```